# Changing values in elements of an array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am working on an assignment and ran into challenging problem. As far as I'm concerned and from what I've learnt the code that follows should be correct however it does not work. Basically what I am trying to is copy a string value into the variable member of a structure the is part of an array passed into a method as  a pointer. What am I missing?

```
typedef struct
{
  char * name; //variable in struct I am trying to access
} Struct;

void foo(Struct * arr) //array of Structs passed into function as a pointer 
{   
  int i = 0;
  while(i++ < 2)    
  {
      arr[i].name = malloc(sizeof(char *));  //assigning memory to variable in each Struct
      arr[i].name = strdup("name");  //copying "name" to variable in each Struct
      printf("C - %s\n", arr[i].name);  //printing out name variable in each Struct
  } 
}

main()
{
  Struct * arr;  //defining pointer
  arr = calloc(2, sizeof(Struct));  //allocating memory so pointer can hold 2 Structs
  foo(arr);  //calling function foo passing pointer into function   
  return 0;
}
```

This code compiles and runs however it does not do what it is designed to do. Forgive me if it is something trivial. I am new to the language C

Comment: `typedef struct Struct` is a very, *very,* ***very bad idea.***

Comment: I used "Struct" just to make it apparent on reading that I am using the pointer as array of structs

Comment: 1. the base type of the array is irrelevant. 2. But it can be seen from the declaration, this is a small piece of code. 3. If you want to make it explicit anyway, then don't typedef and use the `struct` keyword as in `struct Foo array[100];`. Don't cause confusion. Pretty please.

Comment: The while loop is wrong, i will be 1 and then 2.  Should be 0 then 1.  On my system this happened to work but it is not good

Comment: @H2CO3 - If you are still monitoring this, I am curious with what you meant in saying not to use `typedef struct`.  i.e. are you meaning because this is such a small piece of code, not to complicate it?, or do you generally not like `typedef struct` anywhere?  (I `typedef struct` all the time so I can use the alias later)

Comment: @ryyker Neither one. You said: "I used "Struct" just to make it apparent on reading that I am using the pointer as array of structs". But since calling your struct `Struct` is not good, I suggested that, if you want to make it obvious to the reader that your array contains structures, then you don't `typedef` it but you leave the declaration as `struct something array[100];`, i. e. you use the keyword `struct` and the struct tag. This way, it's easy to tell that you have an array of structs.

Comment: @H2CO3 Thank you for pointing this out. I think I was just trying to be too fancy for a simple demonstration

Answer (score 2):

Two issues:

1. `while(i++ < 2)` This line changes the value of `i` as soon as it checks it, so your loop body will not be the same as it was checked.
2. `arr[i].name = strdup("name");` overwrites the value of the `.name` pointer, causing a memory leak of the memory you `malloc()`'ed earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Extending on 2 pointed out correctly already,

```
arr[i].name = strdup("name");
```

Even if you use following instead of above,

```
strcpy(array[i].name, "name");
```

you haven't allocated enough bytes to store the string i.e. this is wrong

```
arr[i].name = malloc(sizeof(char *));
// even if pointer is 8 byte here, concept isn't right
```

Should be something like

```
arr[i].name = malloc(strlen("name")+1);
// or MAX_SIZE where it is greater than the possible "name".
```

Or better yet, remove the malloc at all, strdup takes care of allocation itself

Answer (score -1):

This is not answering your question directly, but addresses an issue to big to put into a comment...
*Additional issue:*  You probably did not intend to allocate only a (char *) worth of memory to a variable intended to hold at least "name".  Change;

`arr[i].name = malloc(sizeof(char *));`

to:

`arr[i].name = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen("name")+1);`  //+1 for '\0'

or better yet, use `char *name="name";`, then:

`arr[i].name = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(name)+1);`

Even more general (and better):

```
char *name;

name = malloc(strlen(someInputString)+1);  
//do stuff with name... 
free(name);
```

Now, you can allocate `name` to any length needed based on the length of `someInputString`.

***[EDIT]***
Etienz, I wanted to address one more thing, alluded to by @H2CO3 above, but not really explained, that I think might be useful to you:
Regarding your desire to have room for two structs, because you typedef'd your struct, you can simply do something like this: (but I am going to change the name you used from Struct to NAME :) *The whole point being that when a struct is created as an array, you do not need to use calloc or malloc to create space for them, it is done as shown below...*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
    char *name;
}NAME;
//use new variable type NAME to create global variables:
NAME n[2], *pN; //2 copies AND pointer created here
//prototype func
int func(NAME *a);
int main()
{
    pN = &n[0];  //pointer initialized here
    func(pN);    //pointer used here (no malloc or calloc)
    printf("name1 is %s\nname 2 is %s", pN[0].name, pN[1].name);
    return 0;
}

int func(NAME *a)
{
    char namme1[]="andrew";
    char namme2[]="billebong";
    //You DO have to allocate the members though
    a[0].name = malloc(strlen(namme1)+1);
    a[1].name = malloc(strlen(namme2)+1);

    strcpy(a[0].name, namme1);
    strcpy(a[1].name, namme2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sizeof(char) not sizeof(char *). plus 1

Comment: Yes, important, and missed that.  Thanks

Comment: Still need the +1 for the terminator.

Comment: Yeah but the concept is still wrong. Allocating length of string based upon size of pointer is pathetic and poor. Who would prevent string going beyond it latter ?

Comment: agree'd.  needed the extra byte.  But regarding @fayyazkl, how much of a tutorial do we do here?  I was just addressing the malloc() (and still got it wrong.)

Comment: Ah...  yes you are right @ryyker i was rather supporting you saying that even if sizeof (char *) works here, it is not right as in OP. The down vote wasn't mine. I won't have typed another answer if if was not already almost done with it.

Comment: Thanks, @fayyazkl,  I recognized that after the fact.  Anyway, a down vote every now and then is not a bad thing.  I think I learn more from them, then up votes.

Comment: @ryyker All this is great for learning thanks. Regarding the array of 2 structs - in my program I simply wanted to demonstrate at some point I want to allocate a number of members that may or may not be stipulated at run time .i.e I want a variable length array